# Update Trigger for Case

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to write a trigger on `Case` that if the `Contact` is null, it will assign a default.  I am just trying to prove the concept right now, I eventually want it to look up the Contact ID from another object.

When I insert a `Case` with a blank `Contact`, it continues to be blank.  I can't see what I am missing.  Thanks for any help.

```
trigger WVCaseTrigger on Case ( before insert) {
  Contact cntct = [Select ID from Contact where ID = '003F000000q6KzW'];
  for(Case cs : trigger.new){
    if (cs.Contact == null){        
        cs.Contact = cntct;
        system.debug('Contact:' + cs.Contact);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field is `ContactId`. I am not sure why your trigger would not detect `null` in this case, but changing to the proper field reference should resolve the issue.

```
if (cs.ContactId == null) cs.ContactId = cntct.Id;
```

Also make sure you have activated the `Apex Trigger`. You can check its metadata for the `IsActive` flag, or examine it through the UI.

Comment: Wow.  That is all it was - thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Always a pleasure. It's the little things, haha. Best of luck. @ToddSells